# Converting geometry to WKT using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, convert, well-known-text

I would like to be able to convert a single feature (or potentially many features) in an ArcGIS layer into [Well Known Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) (WKT) format during a geoprocessing operation using Python and ArcPy (no non-ArcPy modules).  The purpose is to then pass the WKT on to SQL Server Spatial and do additional processing outside of the ArcGIS GP toolset.  Is there a method for converting a ArcGIS geometry features to WKT via ArcPy?

I have already read the following, without finding what I am after:

- [Shapefiles to Text](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/shapefiles-to-text) (references a tool in the deprecated "Samples" toolbox)
- [Convert between ESRI Geometry and WKT](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/convert-between-esri-geometry-and-wkt) (uses ArcObjects or non-ArcPy modules)
- [How to convert a shapefile to WKT?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54870/how-to-convert-a-shapefile-to-wkt) (Uses QGIS and OGR)

There apparently used to be a tool called "[Write Features To Text File](http://arcgishelp.blogspot.com/2010/07/feature-or-shapefile-to-text-file.html)" (which appears to be a Python script) that was in the Samples toolbox, but that toolbox was [deprecated at version 10](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00pv00000003000000) and I cannot find a copy of the Samples Toolbox (I have v10.0) on my machine.  If there are no current solutions, if someone could just point me to a copy of the sample, I would be totally fine with using that tool, too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A da.searchcursor should work for you.

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("path2data", ["SHAPE@WKT"]):
  print row[0]
```

> > POINT Z (-119.53753379999995 49.854383300000052 303.14500000000407)

doc here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001t000000

**Note**: SHAPE@JSON, SHAPE@WKB, and SHAPE@WKT tokens were made available at ArcGIS 10.1 Service Pack 1.

Or, if you're after the samples toolbox like you mentioned - its there, just deprecated. You can call into it with scripts still.
If you need the actual toolbox you can use, its here on the old [Model and Script Gallery](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=F25C5576-1422-2418-A060-04188EBD33A9)

EDIT (extra example)...Because you asked so nicely: :)

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("GPX_Layer", ["SHAPE@WKT"],where_clause="TYPE = 'a'"):
    print row[0]
```

It's just the same as a "select by attributes" type of query/expression. I have a field called "TYPE" and and a value 'a'.

Comment: +1 For including the example---would it be asking too much for a second one showing how the `where_clause` would be implemented? :)

Comment: While I unfortunately do not have access to 10.1 yet, I was ultimately able to update the Python script that you linked to.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for "POINT Z " it seems that the "POINT" do not support 3D in arcpy.

Answer (score 7):

Just adding this in case it's useful for someone...

```
# Convert to WKT by field name (Shape)
file_path = 'C:\shapefile.shp'
query= arcpy.SearchCursor(file_path)
for row in query:
  the_geom=row.getValue('Shape') # Get Geometry field
  wkt = the_geom.WKT # Convert to WKT, can also use WKB, JSON etc
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not equipped to confirm this, but [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) documenting `SearchCursor (arcpy.da)`, discussing the `field_names` parameter, notes the following:

> **[FROM ArcGIS Help 10.1 - SearchCursor (arcpy.da)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000)**
>
> Additional information can be accessed using tokens (such as OID@) in place of field names:
>
> **SHAPE@WKT** —The well-known text (WKT) representation for OGC geometry. It provides a portable representation of a geometry value as a text string
>
> **Note:** SHAPE@JSON, SHAPE@WKB, and **SHAPE@WKT** tokens were **made available at ArcGIS 10.1 Service Pack 1**.

What do you think?

Comment: +1 Also, I think @RyanDalton may be able to find Write Features to Text File [**here**](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=F25C5576-1422-2418-A060-04188EBD33A9).

Answer (score 3):

The **Write Features to Text File** tool can be found **[here](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=F25C5576-1422-2418-A060-04188EBD33A9)**.

There is a related ArcGIS Idea **[here](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000boEsAAI)** that has attracted, in my opinion, perplexingly few votes.