# Importing points in WKB format to QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, csv, import, well-known-binary

I have a CSV file with population data according to specific locations (Points). My problem is that all locations are given in WKB format like that:

```
0101000020E6100000B953EFEEEEB253C0F15BD4CCCC4C05C0
```

How can I visualize my data with QGIS?

I don't know why there is no simple solution. Because to visualize WKB from a database is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create CSV table with attribute "0101000020E6100000B953EFEEEEB253C0F15BD4CCCC4C05C0" (without header). Then import csv table in PostgreSQL/PostGIS database:
first: create table with Point geometry field, WGS1984 SRID

```
CREATE TABLE layer (coord geometry(Point, 4326));
```

second: import in table data from scv table

```
COPY layer("coord") FROM 'D:\data.csv';
```

Then open QGIS, add PostGIS layer (table layer) and receive point feature with coordinates "-78.79583333;-2.6625". This table in PostgreSQL/PostGIS database you caan easy save/export in shapefile.

Comment: Hey HasT, thanks a lot. Now I'm able to import WKB to QGIS :)

Answer (score 8):

An alternative is

- open your CSV as a table without geometry attribute with menu "Layers" > "Add layer" > "Add Delimited Text Layer"
- use a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` to transform the ewkb to a geometry using a query like `SELECT GeomFromEWKB(the_geom) as geom, * FROM out` where `out` is the table name alias of your attribute table and `the_geom` is the column name of EWKB text content

[image]

Comment: Exactly that is what I though about :)

Answer (score 3):

As per your question following plugin [QuickWKT](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickWKT/) will helpful for you.

This plugin opens a dialog where the user can paste(E)WKT and WKB code and see it on the map.

For more details please open [this link](http://www.portailsig.org/content/plugins-qgis-le-format-wkt-ou-la-geometrie-amusante-avec-quickwkt-et-plain-geometry-editor) (Translate this link to the English to understand)

hope it will help for you..

let us know if you have any questions

Comment: Hey Sunil, thanks for your quick response. I already know QuickWKT but I don't know how to import several WKBs. Because I have several thousands of population points. Cheers, Chris

Comment: @Cris I am researching this my end + you need to write python script for that. I am not so expert in this but please go through following posts might be helpful for you   http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58359/how-to-convert-geometry-to-wkt-using-arcpy , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731461/parsing-a-wkt-file