# Import CSV with WKB field to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, well-known-binary

I have a CSV file with a column that is WKB, called `WKB`.

When I import it to QGIS (using "Add Delimited Text Layer"), there seems to be no option for WKB, and the file imports as pure CSV - no geocoded polygons show up on the map, and it thinks the WKB field is a string.

Is there any way to import WKB to QGIS?

Comment: So it is really Well Known Binary?

Comment: WKB in a CSV file is not going to be reliable, since a WKB could have anything in it, including line-feeds, commas, and zero bytes... Is it WKB or WKT, the text version (ie like "POLYGON((1234 123)(313123..." etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/69500/55203) if you're talking about **hex-encoded WKB strings** in delimited files. I think this is still the case. Use WKT / EWKT instead (with tab as separator) or use postgres/postgis instead.