# Import shapefiles into PostGIS using Python with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgis, arcpy, shapefile, psycopg2

I want to import shapefiles to PostGIS using Python with arcpy & psycopg2 to connect to PostGIS.
I don't want to use the existing shapefile loader nor ogr, just write my own import tool.

My steps and where I got stuck:

1. Define shapefile
2. Select column names from shapefile into a list
3. Create SQL CREATE TABLE query with column names of shapefile
4. Insert values from shapefile into PostGIS database

I got stuck at point 4 since I don't really know how to extract the values from the shapefile and insert it into the database taking account of the correct column.

Any idea?

Code example:

```
import arcpy
import psycopg2

arcpy.env.workspace = r"path\to\data"

shp = "BRD.shp"
shp2 = shp[:3]

desc_shp = arcpy.Describe(shp)

#set variables and create list wo OID and Shape attributes
if desc_shp.hasOID:
    print desc_shp.OIDFieldName
    shp_OID = desc_shp.OIDFieldName

print desc_shp.shapeFieldName    
shp_geom = desc_shp.shapeFieldName

fields = desc_shp.fields
field_names = []
for field in fields:
    if not (field.name == shp_OID or field.name == shp_geom):
        field_names.append(field.name)
new_list = field_names
print new_list

sc_da_cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp,shp_geom)
for sc_da_row in sc_da_cursor:
    print sc_da_row[0]

# PostGIS part after here

user = "postgres"
pw = "postgres"
db = "pypg"
host = "localhost"
port = 5432

conn_obj = psycopg2.connect(database=db, user=user, password=pw, host=host, port=port)
cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()

sql_createtable = "CREATE TABLE " + shp2 + "(" + shp_OID + " serial PRIMARY KEY," + 
shp_geom + " geometry," + new_list[0] + " VARCHAR(100)," +  new_list[1] +
" VARCHAR(100))"

sql_insert = "INSERT INTO " + shp2 + "(" + shp_geom + ") VALUES(" + str(sc_da_row[0]) +
")"
cur_obj.execute(sql_insert)

conn_obj.commit()
conn_obj.close()
cur_obj.close()
```

Comment: Use Shapely, perhaps, see this post: http://www.macwright.org/2012/10/31/gis-with-python-shapely-fiona.html.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot include other methods/tools like Shapely and so on. It must be possible only with arcpy and pscopg2.

Comment: Perhaps you could post what you have done so far?

Comment: I added a code example

Comment: I don't know ArcPy, but you can use the GeoJSON, WKT or WKB formats of the geometry ([Python - How to convert geometry to WKT using ArcPy?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58359/how-to-convert-geometry-to-wkt-using-arcpy) for example) to import it in PostGIS

Answer (score 2):

I just used the below code to transfer a shapefile into PostGIS. I saw your post and thought it might help. The Shape@WKT makes it really easy to transfer the geometry. Everything is hard coded and works which I am happy with and will probably revisit at a later date when my coding improves. If anything is not clear please let me know.

```
import psycopg2, arcpy
# shapefile to get data from
data = ("C:/shapefiles/georgia_counties.shp")
# fields I want from shapefile
fields = ["AREANAME", "TotPop90", "PctRural", "PctBach", "PctEld", "PctFB", "PctPov", "PctBlack", "ID", "Shape@WKT"]

# pscopg2 connection, replace *** and *** with your values
connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=*** user=***")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS georgia")
cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE georgia (
        id SERIAL,
        name VARCHAR,
        totpop INTEGER,
        pctrural DOUBLE PRECISION,
        pctbach DOUBLE PRECISION,
        pcteld DOUBLE PRECISION,
        pctfb DOUBLE PRECISION,
        pctpov DOUBLE PRECISION,
        pctblack DOUBLE PRECISION,
        county_id VARCHAR,

        PRIMARY KEY (county_id))
""")

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT AddGeometryColumn('georgia', 'geom', 32616, 'MULTIPOLYGON', 2)
""")

# use arcpy to get attribute data, populate PostGIS using psycopg2
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(data, fields) as da_cursor:
    for row in da_cursor:
        wkt = row[9]
        # the id was transferring as a float so this is just to remove decimal
        id = int(row[8])
        # this was tough - everything needs to be a string and text being inserted wrapped in '' including wkt
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO georgia (name, totpop, pctrural, pctbach, pcteld, pctfb, pctpov, pctblack, county_id, geom) VALUES (" + '\'' + row[0] + '\'' + ", " + str(row[1]) + ", " + str(row[2]) + ", " + str(row[3]) + ", " + str(row[4]) + ", " + str(row[5]) + ", " + str(row[6]) + ", " + str(row[7]) + ", " + str(id) + ", ST_GeometryFromText(" + "'" + wkt + "', 32616))")

connection.commit()
```

Comment: You can clean up the `cursor.execute` call a bit by passing your variables in as parameters...checkout the psycopg2 [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

You might also want to consider using `SHAPE@WKB` and `ST_GeomFromWKB` so that you're transferring an exact copy of the geometry to the database.

Comment: While you're at it, you can add a spatial index as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty new to the whole pyscopg2 python connection but it is super useful. I recently wrote this script. I hard coded it(would be more useful if I wrote a function) but nevertheless it works totally fine.

*id would recommend defining your database connection at the top of your scripts up by your import statements, for a more organized code structure

*when creating tables and inserting values into columns avoid using 'columnname'+value+'columname2'+value2 etc... it gets clunky and hard to read. try using the `.format()` function or `%s` to insert values and create tables

```
import arcpy
import psycopg2
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='shapefile' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='mypass'") #connecting to DB
cur = conn.cursor()  #setting up connection cursor
cur.execute('''drop table drugpoints''')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE drugpoints
            (id serial primary key,
             Name text,
             Type  text,
             x float,
             y float,
             geom geometry);''')
conn.commit()
arcpy.env.workspace = "path"
shp = "path\\drugfreezone.shp"
for row in gp.Searchcursor(shp):
    ty = str(row.type_)
    name = str(row.name)
    x = float(row.x)
    y = float(row.y)
    print ty, name, x, y
    cur.execute('''insert into drugpoints(Name, Type, x, y, geom)
                    values(%s,%s,%s,%s,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s,%s), 4269))'''
                    ,(ty, name, x,y,x,y))
    conn.commit()
```