# Converting PostGIS table to Feature Set using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, postgis, arcgis-pro, export, feature-set

I am writing an ArcPy script (ArcGIS Pro) to export tile in the area of interest with help of `arcpy.ExportTileCache_management()`. I am getting the area of interest from a table in PostGIS. As far as I read in the documentation are the area of interest must be Feature Set data type.

I tried `FeatureSet.from_json` to convert my table in PostGIS but it was not successful. I kept getting the following error

```
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-90516b90cd60>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/ncipa/PycharmProjects/arcpy/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/ncipa/PycharmProjects/arcpy')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/ncipa/PycharmProjects/arcpy/test.py", line 518, in <module>
    areaofinterest = FeatureSet.from_json(polygon)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\feature.py", line 694, in from_json
    return FeatureSet.from_dict(json.loads(json_str))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'
```

How can I convert the record in my table in PostGIS to Feature Set?

```py
# Connect and query tables in Postgresql
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user='xxx',
                                  password='xxx',
                                  host="xxx",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="xxx")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Fetch records
    postgreSQL_select_Query1 = "select pgnr,  ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) from xxx"
    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query1)
    records = cursor.fetchall()


except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL")

finally:
    # closing database connection.
    if (connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")

for i, row in enumerate(records):

    polygon = json.loads(row[1])

    cacheSource = r"E:\xxx_cache"
    cacheTarget = r"E:\_xx"
    cacheName = "Target"
    cacheType = "TILE_CACHE"
    storageFormat = "Compact"
    scales = "100000"
    areaofinterest = FeatureSet.from_json(polygon)

    arcpy.ExportTileCache_management(cacheSource, cacheTarget, cacheName,
                                     cacheType, storageFormat, scales, areaofinterest)

    if i == 0:
        break
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the way in which is was "not successful". Your code snippet could be cut down to a single geometry, with legible contents.

Comment: I added the error message that I am receiving when I run the code snippet above.

Comment: What is this? `FeatureSet.from_json` ? arcpy has a FeatureSet -- but based on your code, I'm not sure if this is an arcpy FeatureSet or something else?

Comment: I am writing an arcpy script for the first time and I do not have a good knowledge obviously. As it is written in the question, I wanted to use the 'Export Tile Cache' (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/export-tile-cache.htm). I read in the documentation that the data type of AOI must be a Feature Set. Therefore, I went on searching how I can convert the records in my table and then I saw FeatureSet.from_json in the following link https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.FeatureSet.from_json and used it.

Comment: ArcGIS can natively read PostgreSQL/PostGIS tables as feature classes (I do this 10-12 hours/day), So using psycopg2 to do this seems the long way around the lake.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have used "Create Database Connection" to create a native connection as you suggested. But I still can not get it as feature classes. I am following this https://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/arcsdesqlexecute.htm

Comment: Ah my ignorance! 
egdb = r"E:\xxxx.sde\db_name.schema.table_name" >> It gives me the feature class!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things here that might be causing your problem.

1. I assume this is an actual arcpy FeatureSet: `areaofinterest = FeatureSet.from_json(polygon)` The proper way to "put something" into a featureset is via `load`. [Documentation reference](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/featureset.htm) That said, I'm not entirely sure what it is you're getting out of your postgres connection. Its very possible that output simply cannot be pumped into a feature set. It may require some transformation. I just don't know. Or maybe you can use `FeatureSet.load()`, and it'll just work. If that's the case, you're done.
2. Input tool parameters can sometimes be confusing. You're right, that yes, the *area of interest* parameter requires a feature set as input. However, in the Esri-GP-Tool world, a feature set can be multiple things. The feature set parameter is a subset of feature class. It's used because when you're in the app (ArcMap / Pro) it allows one to draw features directly on the map right before they run the tool. This allows a user to skip the process of going and making a brand new featureclass and digitizing a shape. So, you could provide a featureclass as input into this parameter instead of an *arcpy featureset*.

Suggestion -- (this is based on what I *think* you can get out of your postgres connection) Throw the feature set idea away, just forget about it completely. Try to figure out how to get the postgres connection >> data (layer) into a "esri featureclass". Apologies, I can't offer a true solution as I'm not familiar with the `psycopg2` module and what it provides. There are some hits here on GIS.SE that may provide some start points.

- [using psycopg2 with arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144132/import-shapefiles-into-postgis-using-python-with-psycopg2)
- Lots of other posts, but the majority specific to pushing data INTO postgres, not getting it out

Comment: The output of my postgres connection is a list and each record in the table is a tuple in the list.  I have already been looking into PostGIS into an "esri featureclass" option. As a worst-case scenario, I will export my table in PostGIS into a shapefile via ogr2ogr and continue from there.