# Preparing geometry for psycopg2 using ArcPy without SHAPE@WKT?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, geometry, well-known-text, psycopg2

Trying to print out a polygon shapefile in WKT format in a standalone script. I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and use the da modules all the time. I have seen this post [Converting geometry to WKT using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58359/how-to-convert-geometry-to-wkt-using-arcpy) and have copied and pasted that code to use on my polygon shapefile and it does not work. The error I get is

```
RuntimeError: unknown geometry token 'SHAPE@WKT'

import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Ralph\\Desktop\\sql"
shp = "C:\\Users\\Ralph\\Desktop\\sql\\states2.shp"
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["SHAPE@WKT"]):
    print row[0]
```

I know it is mentioned in the above post that this token was made available for service pack 1. I am starting to think I do not have service pack 1 nor do I know how to check if I have it. I plan on reading this polygon in a easy format so I can import it using psycopg2 to postgreSQL. Is there another way to read polygon geometries for this task only by using Arcpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had more success when I specify just `SHAPE@` as my cursor field and then request the `WKT` (or other formats) when querying each row.  Try changing where you request the `WKT`:

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["SHAPE@"]):
    print row[0].WKT
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the reason you get that error message is that your version of ArcGIS may be too early.

The [ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop Help on arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) says that it is a valid syntax:

> SHAPE@WKT —The well-known text (WKT) representation for OGC geometry.
>   It provides a portable representation of a geometry value as a text
>   string.

My recollection was that this particular token was added a version or two after ArcPy Data Access and the `SHAPE@` token first became available at 10.1 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58362 from @KHibma says:

> Note: SHAPE@JSON, SHAPE@WKB, and SHAPE@WKT tokens were made available
>   at ArcGIS 10.1 Service Pack 1.